# How to override JS widgets in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo-9

I want to over ride web.datepicker widget in my custom module. How to do this? Actually I want to disable all days except Saturday in Calendar

Comment: Follow this link: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/javascript.html

This will help you to understand base JS of odoo v9 and then you can easily override it.

Comment: Thanks but I did it on my own :)